# How can I avoid circular import in django models?

Tags: python, django, circular-dependency, nameerror

I need to import **address** into my **UserProfile** so I could keep track of all addresses of a person in his profile, also I wanted to import **owner** into my **AddressBook** to know which profile I am saving this address to.

Below is the code I tried but since it is a circular import I am not able to do that, how do I overcome this situation. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    address = models.ManyToManyField(AddressBook, blank=True)

class AddressBook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    has_address = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17) # validators should be a list
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Comment: Use `models.ManyToManyField('app1.AddressBook', ...)` and `models.ForeignKey('app2.UserProfile', ...)`. If the models are in the same app, you don't need the `app1.` and `app2.` prefixes.

Comment: @Alasdair could you confirm If I need to re-write this code `address = models.ManyToManyField('app1.AddressBook', blank=True)`  `owner = models.ForeignKey('app2.UserProfile', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)` . If the models are in the same app, you don't need the `app1.` and `app2.` prefixes....How is this done??...I am not sure about this I am still a beginner in django, please help me on this

Comment: You need to replace `app1` and `app2` with the actual app names. You haven’t said what apps those models are in.

Comment: @Alasdair Both the models are in the same app that's named _account_. So according to your previous statement if the models are in same app it must work fine ryt? i.e., I have it this way:             account-->models.py--> `class UserProfile(..) ..... class AddressBook(...).....`